# Is there a way to turn off the previewing of folded items when hovering on a (+) in PyDev?

Tags: python, ide, pydev

I am referring to this behaviour:

[image]

(Windows doesn't include the mouse cursor in the screen shot, I'm hovered on the uppermost (+) here.)

I find this incredibly annoying in some cases, especially with larger methods.

In `Window->Preferences->PyDev->Editor->Hover`, I have both checkboxes blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not currently possible...

Now, in case someone decides to provide a patch, below is what would be involved in doing it ( after getting PyDev: http://pydev.org/developers.html )

Create a preference for that in org.python.pydev.editor.hover.PyHoverPreferencesPage and customize the hover control creator for the projection... i.e.: fProjectionSupport.setHoverControlCreator() at org.python.pydev.editor.codefolding.PyEditProjection.createPartControl(Composite)